# While I migrate from Android to AndroidX , Error in implementing google play services in my projects. What might be the solution?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, androidx

Here is my app level `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "threecallistos.jumperr"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.0'
}
```

and `gradle.properties` is here

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

When I remove

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
```

From `app.build` file it works fine. But I have to work with google maps and services, so I searched here and there but couldn't find any proper solution. 
I found one suggestion in github as

> I believe this is because com.google.firebase transitively depends on com.android.support:support-v4. To address this you should be able to set android.enableJetifier=true in your gradle.properties file, which will "automatically convert existing third-party libraries as if they were written for AndroidX"

and I already did this but doesn't work!

I got error when I build/ run the project

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present: 
>   android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel, sources=[Unknown
>   source  file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)} Caused by:
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while 
>   merging dex archives:

Please give me some solution.

Answer (score 7):

There has been multiple questions with *completely different* errors that actually all derive from migrating to AndroidX libraries in Android Studio v3.1. I was getting all sorts of weird errors that just could not be resolved without reverting back to Support libraries. Therefore, you may see this same answer for different questions. Because the questions are about errors that differ so greatly in description and context, they are not duplicate questions and therefore all should be answered with this solution. Ironically this explanation is longer than the solution, and was included to help admins understand.

The solution is:
Android Studio v3.2+ resolves this issue. It also adds a "Migrate to AndroidX" item under the Refactor menu to make the migration easier. No work-around or rollback required. It is important to migrate to AndroidX libraries, as the old support libraries will end after stable v28 Support libraries are released.

Update Android Studio from the beta channel to use 3.2+ or wait until a stable version is released in the very near future.

EDIT: 9/25/18 - the v3.2 stable version is now available in the stable channel.